# Jquery selector for each first appearance of a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

i have a script which generate the following HTML code :

```
<table class="table">
<tr><td class="head">Title</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cat">Featured</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cat">Hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cat">Hello</td></tr></table>

<table class="table">
<tr><td class="head">Title</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cat">Featured</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cat">Hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cat">Hello</td></tr></table>


<table class="table">
<tr><td class="head">Title</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cat">Featured</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cat">Hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cat">Hello</td></tr></table>
```

I need to style the first cat class "Featured" ! i'm using jquery but i dont know hot to choose the right selector ?

i tried

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".table .cat:first").css("color","blue");
})
```

but i doesn't the right job, it just select the first element with class="cat".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change to:

```
$(".table").find(".cat:first").css("color","blue");
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/NLVH2/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate the tables like so

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.table').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.cat:first').css('color', 'blue');
    })
})
```

Here's the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vFT46/

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
$('.table').find('.cat:first').css('color','blue');
```

to get the first `.cat` child of `.table`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JVTpG/)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $(".table .head").next().css("color", "blue");
});
```

Comment: @hutchbat -- thanks...also you should accept one of the other poster's answers if it was correct ;)